# Python "\x00" filled / utf-32 string from cStringIO

Tags: python, unicode

Through cStringIO of another system, I wrote some unicode via:

`u'content-length'.encode('utf-8')`

and on reading this back using, `unicode( stringio_fd.read(),'utf-8')`, I get:

u'c\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00l\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00g\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00'

printing the above in the terminal gives me the right value, but of course, I can't do anything useful:

> print unicode("c\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00l\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00g\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00")
>
> content-length
>
> print unicode("c\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00l\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00g\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00") == u'content-length'
>
> False

What's the quickest, cheapest way to turn this string into a string equivalent to `u'content-type'` ? I can't change from cStringIO

---

### Updates

While philhag's answer is correct, it appears the problem is:

> StringIO.StringIO(u'content-type').getvalue().encode('utf-8')
>
> 'content-type'
>
> StringIO.StringIO(u'content-type').getvalue().encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
>
> u'content-type'
>
> cStringIO.StringIO(u'content-type').getvalue().encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
>
> u'c\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00y\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00'
>
> cStringIO.StringIO(u'content-type').getvalue().encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8').decode('utf-32')
>
> u'content-type'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause is that `cStringIO.StringIO(unicode_object)` produces a nonsense.

The [current 2.X docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#cStringIO.StringIO) on docs.python.org say

> Unlike the StringIO module, this module is not able to accept Unicode
>   strings that cannot be encoded as plain ASCII strings.

This is unhelpful and incorrect; see below. The `chm` version of the docs supplied with the win32 installer for CPython 2.7.2 and 2.6.6 follow that with this sentence:

> Calling StringIO() with a Unicode string parameter populates the
>   object with the buffer representation of the Unicode string instead of
>   encoding the string.

This is a correct description of the behaviour (see below). The behaviour is not brilliant. I can't imagine a good reason for that sentence being removed from the web docs.

Behaving badly:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>>> import StringIO, cStringIO, sys
>>> StringIO.StringIO(u"fubar").getvalue()
u'fubar' <<=== unicode object
>>> cStringIO.StringIO(u"fubar").getvalue()
'f\x00u\x00b\x00a\x00r\x00' <<=== str object
cStringIO.StringIO(u"\u0405\u0406").getvalue()
'\x05\x04\x06\x04' <<=== "accepts"
>>> sys.maxunicode
65535 # your sender presumably emits 1114111 (wide unicode)
>>> sys.byteorder
'little'
```

So in general all one needs to do is know/guess the endianness and unicode-width of the sender's Python and decode the mess with `UTF-(16|32)-(B|L)E`.

In your case the sender is being rather Byzantine; for example `u'content-length'.encode('utf-8')` is the `str` object `'content-length'` which bears a remarkable similarity to what you started with. Also `foo.encode(utf8').decode('utf8')` produces either `foo` or an exception.

Comment: +1: Thanks for the detailed explanation John Machin. And you're right, they should have left that line in the docs! Thanks again, this may end my encoding based suffering.

Comment: Accept for the good explanation and identification of the root cause in cStringIO ... also, using my_cstringio.write(u'hello') doesn't have quite as bad an effect.

Comment: cStringIO behavior changes in 2.7.3

Answer (score 6):

Something along the way is encoding your values as UTF-32. Simply decode them:

```
>>> b = u"c\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00\
... n\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00l\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00\
... n\x00\x00\x00g\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00"
>>> b.decode('utf-32')
u'content-length'
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, that works for my example :) ... The "something along the way" seems to be mixing encodings too ... which is odd as it is .encode('utf-8')->StringIO and back through cStringIO->decode('utf-8')

Comment: `UTF-32` "works" only because both the source system and the target system have the same byte order (in this case little-endian).

Comment: @JohnMachin I believe that's where `UTF-32BE` and `UTF-32LE` come in right?